# Conditional Formatting by Date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Summary: Is it possible to auto highlight an entire row based on one cell with a date in it when that date becomes over one year old?

I have a spreadsheet that has a list of recently sold apartment buildings which are used for comps. I’m only supposed to keep comps for properties sold within the last year. Currently I am able to highlight the cell with the date with a red background using conditional formatting so when I update I can easily notice it and remove that row. However, is it possible to highlight the entire row?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With a formula rule, the reference to the date cell anchored (`$`) for column and the `Apply to range` set to whole rows.